# PowerShell: Script cannot set a parameter

Tags: powershell-2.0

For a script that should be compatible to powerShell 2, I have a param called $exeLoc, declared as follows:
    Param(
     [parameter()]
        [alias("el")]
        $exeLoc=  '......\sw' )

I try to set that parameter, from relative to absolute in a function, as follows:

```
Function FromRelToAbs()
{
   Push-Location $exeLoc
   $Global:exeLoc = (Join-path $PWD -ChildPath '\Vis.exe' )
  Pop-Location
}
```

However, after calling the function above, the value of $exeLoc does not change.

The above code works perfectly on powersell v3 AND in powershell v2 ISE. It does not work properly on a powershell v2 window ( not ISE )

Any ideas ?

Comment: The global scope sounds fishy. Parameters are variables local to their functions; did you perhaps mean `$parent:exeLoc` if you're calling that function from the one with the declared parameter?

Comment: This is a script parameter, not a function parameter; i.e. this is declared at the beginning of the script, and I meant for them to be used as globals. Did I get it wrong ?

Comment: In that case I think the `script` scope would be more appropriate. But I don't have much experience using various scopes, to be honest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it your script is something along these lines:

```
param($x = 2)

write-output "[script] Value of x is 2"

function blah {
  $global:x = 5
  write-output "[blah] Setting x as 5"
}

Write-Output "Calling function blah"
blah
Write-Output "[script] Value of x is $x"
```

You set the variable in the script; and within the script is a function that refers to the variable in the global scope and sets its value.

If I try the above on my machine (PowerShell v2) it does set the variable correctly. Maybe I understood your script wrong?

Comment: This is basically what I'm trying to do. The only difference is that I have a func that prints $x value before and after the 'blah'. On my machine, ps v2, this only works in ISE. In a shell, it does not set $x...

Comment: I realized why it is working for me  but not you. I was dot-sourcing the script (habit!) whereas you are just running it.

When dot-sourcing the script there's only a global scope, but when running the script normally there's a global scope and a script scope. So when you set $global:var you actually changing the variable in the global scope, not the one in the script scope. Change $global: to $script: in your code and it should work.